# Impose one image on another programatically(overrwrite). Android

Tags: java, android, android-image, overwrite

I have 2 images inside my app. First one it's some kind of map with empty boxes. Second one it's simply correct mark. In some cases I need to impose this correct mark on some of this empty boxes which are placed on first image. There is an option to do that ? how to manage it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need a combination of `Canvas` and `Bitmap`.

For example:

```
Bitmap imageWithEmptyBoxes = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
           R.drawable.imageWithEmptyBoxes);
Bitmap imageCheckMark = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
            R.drawable.imageCheckMark);
...
Canvas c = new Canvas(imageWithEmptyBoxes);
c.drawBitmap(imageCheckMark, ...);
```

Comment: Sounds good, but tell me where and how I need to pass location of this empty boxes ? this is quite problematic

Comment: Well, drawBitmap() takes x and y coordinates of the location where to draw the checkmarks. These coordinates correspond to the upper left corner of your white boxes. Depending on how you store them, you can read the coordinates from here.